# How to retrieve commit after hard reset to prior commit?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Following image shows the working of a hard reset. How to retrieve the file.txt (v3)? Is there a way to push the head ahead?

[image]

Comment: The commit (here above `38eb946`) is not part of the branch any more, but it still exists in the repo. You might recreate a branch there, or reset the current one on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recover it from the **reflog**:

```sh
git reflog --all

# Write down the commit hash you need to recover

git cherry-pick <commit-hash-to-recover>
```

Comment: Is the reflow always retained? I mean it never loses information? So the hard reset commit can be recovered always?

Comment: Can be recovered before a git garbage collection.

Comment: @variable: reflogs are maintained for as long as they're maintained. This is configurable: both whether reflogs are maintained at all, and if so, how long an entry *in* a reflog lasts. The default for user (non-bare) repositories is such that entries will stick around for 30 days at least. That said, don't drop references you intend to keep: don't use `git reset --hard` to move around in history; that's not what it's for.

Comment: @torek - does reset done using mixed or soft mode also require reflog to recover?

Comment: @variable: it's not really the `--hard` option that's the problem, it's the moving-around that's the problem. But you wouldn't move around with mixed or soft reset just to look at a commit in the first place, since that doesn't update your working tree files. The general idea here is that if you want to look at a historical commit, use a detached-HEAD checkout (`git switch --detach <commit>` for instance) to do that.

Comment: Or `git branch newbranchname <commit>` ?